# Joomla - Update Name in the Users table

Tags: php, joomla

I have a Joomla 3 installed in my local machine.

I've edited the default registration page to hide the Name field, wherein instead of using the full name as a field, I've divided it into First Name, Middle Name and Last Name.

Fortunately, the records being saved is successful and I can update them too.

The problem is when the administrator starts managing the list of users, there's no link to proceed. This means the field with the link, which is the Name field (the full one) is blank.

My objective is that upon registration, I can fill that field out with a concatenated first, middle and last name.

How can I do this in Joomla 3?

Thanks.

Comment: The correct way to do that is by [creating a profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to develop a custom user plugin to manage this properly.  In addition, if you are going to write the plugin you should go ahead incorporate the entire use case into.  Below is a quick draft of how your main plugin file would look:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgUserCustom extends JPlugin
{
    public function __construct(& $subject, $config) 
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
    }

    // Called while Joomla is loading the form for the view
    // This is where you would remove or alter fields
    // and load your custom xml form definition for the 
    // first, middle and last names
    public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
    {

        // Confirm valid JForm object or exit
        if (!($form instanceof JForm))
        {
            $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');
            return false;
        }

        // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
        // If the active view isn't listed in array exit as plugin not needed
        //
        // com_users.registration = front end registration form
        // com_users.profile = front end edit profile form
        // com_users.user = back end administrators form
        if (!in_array($form->getName(), array('com_users.registration', 'com_users.profile', 'com_users.user'))) {
            return true;
        }

        // The core JForm object for the view will be loaded
        // manipulate the fields any way you like
        // In below example, the name field will be removed
        // from the users registration, profile and admin user manager view
        if (in_array($form->getName(), array('com_users.registration', 'com.users.profile', 'com_users.user'))) {
            $form->removeField('name');

            // Now add the form xml path for your custom name fields
            // In this example the plugin has a forms directory
            JForm::addFormPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/forms');
            $form->loadFile("custom", false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // This is where Joomla loads any existing data into the form field
    // and where you would take the standard name field and separate
    // into first, middle and last name values and attach to data object.
    // The data object property names must match the field name in your
    // xml form definition file.
    public function onContentPrepareData($context, $data) {

        // Verify you are in the correct form before manipulating data
        if (!in_array($context, array('com_users.profile','com_users.user', 'com_users.registration'))) {
            return true;
        }


        // explode core name field into parts, attach to core data object
        // as first, middle and last name and unset name data.  
        // CAUTION:  You should implement check to verify middle name entered
        // or not by verifying if parts array length is 2 or 3

        $parts = explode(" ", $data->name);
        $data->first_name = $parts[0];
        $data->middle_name = $parts[1];
        $data->last_name = $parts[2];

        unset($data->name);

        }

        return true;
    }

    // This method fires before Joomla save the user data and is where
    // you should combine the first, middle and last names into one name
    // and attach to data object and remove references to first, middle and
    // last names.
    public function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isNew, $data) {

          // Manicure data before save, implode first, middle and last name 
          // into one field and add to data object, unset first, middle and last
          // name from data object
          $data->name = implode(" ", array($data->first_name, $data->middle_name, $data->last_name));
          unset($data->first_name);
          unset($data->middle_name);
          unset($data->last_name);


         return true;       
    }

    public function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error) 
    {
         return true;
    }

    public function onUserAfterDelete($user, $succes, $msg)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function onUserLogin($user, $options) 
    {

        return true;
    }

    public function onUserLogout($credentials, $options) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

I added links to writing a plugin to help you in creating and packaging the installation ZIP to install the plugin.  I also attached a link for creating xml form definitions.

Good Luck!

http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla
http://docs.joomla.org/XML_JForm_form_definitions

Answer (score 0):

You can manage/manipulate user data using a [User Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User).  This link will show you how to use `example.php` (which, I believe, is included with the Joomla installation).  You're probably most interested in `function onUserBeforeSave`, and may not even need your module changes if you manipulate their input before Joomla saves it.